# .net dictionary and lookup add / update

Tags: c#, collections

I am sick of doing blocks of code like this for various bits of code I have:

```
if (dict.ContainsKey[key]) {  
    dict[key] = value;  
}  
else {  
    dict.Add(key,value);  
}
```

and for lookups (i.e. key -> list of value)

```
if (lookup.ContainsKey[key]) {  
    lookup[key].Add(value);  
}  
else {  
    lookup.Add(new List<valuetype>);  
    lookup[key].Add(value);  
}
```

Is there another collections lib or extension method I should use to do this in one line of code no matter what the key and value types are?

e.g.

```
dict.AddOrUpdate(key,value)  
lookup.AddOrUpdate(key,value)
```

Comment: Is `lookup` an `ILookup<key, value>`?  I'm thinking not because it shouldn't have a `ContainsKey` method.  Just confirming .NET didn't change lookups since question asked, because was looking for a way to update an `ILookup`...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As Evgeny says, the indexer will already replace existing values - so if you *just* want to unconditionally set the value for a given key, you can do

```
dictionary[key] = value;
```

The more interesting case is the "get a value, or insert it if necessary". It's easy to do with an extension method:

```
public static TValue GetOrCreateValue<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
     TKey key,
     TValue value)
{
    return dictionary.GetOrCreateValue(key, () => value);
}

public static TValue GetOrCreateValue<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
     TKey key,
     Func<TValue> valueProvider)
{
    TValue ret;
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
    {
        ret = valueProvider();
        dictionary[key] = ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note the use of a delegate to create the default value - that facilitates scenarios like the "list as value" one; you don't want to create the empty list unless you have to:

```
dict.GetOrCreateValue(key, () => new List<int>()).Add(item);
```

Also note how this only performs the lookup once if the key is already present - there's no need to do a `ContainsKey` and *then* look up the value. It still requires two lookups when it's creating the new value though.

Comment: And a note for .net core+ users: If the use case is "predominantly values will be added, sometimes they already exist and should be updated" one can use `TryAdd` and act upon the false return value to perform the update. It performs two lookups for update, but as those cases are in the minority it's better than performing two lookups for an add. Note that on .net framework, TryAdd is an extension that relies on ContainsKey so you'd end up performing two lookups anyway; achieving a single lookup add-or-update would (I believe) require subclassing dictionary in either .net flavor..

Answer (score 17):

When updating you don't need to perform a check. Simply use:

```
dict[key] = value
```

It will replace any existing value. When retrieving the value unfortunately there is no convenient single method (like `setdefault` in Python), but you could make your own extension method. Something like this:

```
if (!lookup.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
     value = new List<T>();
     lookup.Add(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ConcurrentDictionary in .NET 4.0 has [this nice method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665(VS.100).aspx). You could also write an extension method for this.

Answer (score 3):

If working with .NET Framework 4 or later, you can use the [AddOrUpdate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665%28VS.100%29.aspx)

```
dict.AddOrUpdate(key,value)
```

add or update is like this

```
dict[key] = value;
```

Comment: This is only available for `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Yes, you use it with Concurrent Dictionary because you don't want to fall into a trap where you check the add condition, determine that you need to do an add, then have something else do the add behind your back.  AddOrUpdate makes it atomic, i believe.

Answer (score 3):

I like [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675(v=vs.110).aspx) method of [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), but I like performance of Dictionary collection too :) So, this is extension method for all classes implementing [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static TValue AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
    TKey key,
    TValue addValue,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)
{
    TValue existing;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out existing))
    {
        addValue = updateValueFactory(key, existing);
        dict[key] = addValue;
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(key, addValue);
    }

    return addValue;
}


public static TValue AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue> addValueFactory,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)
{
    TValue existing;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out existing))
    {
        existing = updateValueFactory(key, existing);
        dict[key] = existing;
    }
    else
    {
        existing = addValueFactory(key);
        dict.Add(key, existing);
    }

    return existing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if there is a method like you ask for, but you could write a small function for it, or use the try catch exception, presumably if you try adding a value that already exists it will throw an exception. If you catch that and ignore it... Just a suggestion